# Bugsnag showing url of minified files instead of upload sourcemap files

Tags: reactjs, source-maps, bugsnag

I am using bugsnag for error reporting.
To show stacktrace of errors bugsnag needs sourcemaps, which I am trying to upload to bugsnag using this documentation:
[Uploading source map](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/javascript/source-maps/#uploading-source-maps-recommended)
github: [bugsnag sourcemaps](https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-sourcemaps)

I have used upload API of bugsnag to upload sourcemaps on bugsnags for my react app and then I am deleting the sourcemaps from my host.
After doing this when I checked bugsnag sourcemaps setting it is showing me minified files URLs in "Source URL" column.

[image: bugsnag sourcemaps]

I am getting a message:

> Source mapping failed: A source map could not be found Could not find
> original source file and line numbers because the source map could not
> be downloaded from https://hostname/minifiedFileName.js.map. Ensure
> that your source map is accessible from our servers or upload them to
> us. (Note that events are not reprocessed after source maps are
> uploaded.)

This is because after uploading I am deleting sourcemaps from build. I am assuming with upload API sourcemaps are uploaded to bugsnag and we don't need to keep sourcemaps at our host.

I am not understanding what step am I missing in uploading sourcemaps to bugsnag.

I have created a file process-bugsnag-sourcemaps.js

```
const { upload } = require('bugsnag-sourcemaps');
const reportBuild = require('bugsnag-build-reporter');
const glob = require('glob');
const fs = require('fs');

function uploadSourceMap(sourceMap) {
  const minifiedFile = sourceMap.replace('.map', '');
  const minifiedFileServerPath = `${minifiedFile.split('/')[2]}/${
    minifiedFile.split('/')[3]
  }/${minifiedFile.split('/')[4]}`;

  return upload({
    apiKey: config.get('BUGSNAG_API_KEY'),
    appVersion,
    overwrite: true,
    minifiedUrl: `${config.get('STATIC_PATH')}${minifiedFileServerPath}`,
    sourceMap,
    minifiedFile,
    projectRoot: __dirname,
    uploadSources: true,
  });
}

/**
 * Find, upload and delete Source Maps
 */
function processSourceMaps() {
  findSourceMaps((error, files) =>
    Promise.all(files.map(uploadSourceMap))
      .then(() => {
        deleteFiles(files);
        notifyRelease();
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      })
  );
}
processSourceMaps();
```

This is the Article from where I referenced code to write upload function: [Upload Create React App source maps to Bugsnag for easier debugging and delete them afterwards for security](https://medium.com/sovtech-insights/upload-create-react-app-source-maps-to-bugsnag-for-easier-debugging-and-delete-them-afterwards-for-c834c729506a)

Why sourcemaps are not uploaded on bugsnag and why bugsnag is trying to access sourcemaps from my minfifiedUrl host I specified in upload function?

It would be great if someone point out which step am I missing?

I have added this [issue](https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-sourcemaps/issues/61) on github repository

Comment: Did you find any solution for this. I am having similar issue for VUE JS application.

Comment: @MOHAMMEDABDULHASEEB, Hi, As far I remember I did not change any thing in the process and after some time the source maps started showing up correctly.